# How to convert SDL_surface into an uint8_t array?

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I'm trying to convert SDL_surface into my own Color structure:

```
struct Color
{
    uint8_t r, g, b, a;

    explicit Color(const uint8_t p_r = 0, const uint8_t p_g = 0, const float uint8_t = 0, const uint8_t p_a = 255);
};
```

What I'm trying to do is:

1. load png file into SDL_Surface.

   ```
   SDL_Surface * img = IMG_Load("pngfilePath.png");
   ```
2. Convert SDL_Surfaceformat into RGBA format

   ```
   SDL_Surface * rgbaImage = SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat(img, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA32, 0);
   ```
3. Allocate memory to my "color" array

   ```
   Color *palette = new Color[rgbaImage->w * rgbaImage->h];
   ```
4. And finally, I want to copy all the png color information into my "color" array.

   I'm currently stuck at this stage.

   ```
   uint32_t* pixels = static_cast<uint32_t *>(rgbaImage->pixels);
   uint8_t r, g, b, a;
   for(int i = 0; i < rgbaImage->h; ++i)
   {
       for(int j = 0; j < rgbaImage->w; ++j)
       {
           SDL_GetRGBA(pixels[j + i * rgbaImage->w],
               rgbaImage->format, &r, &g, &b, &a);

           palette[j + i * rgbaImage->w].r = r;
           palette[j + i * rgbaImage->w].g = g;
           palette[j + i * rgbaImage->w].b = b;
           palette[j + i * rgbaImage->w].a = a;
       }
   }
   ```

   This is how I want to save all the information into my "color" structure.

Is there a more efficient way to do this? it seems like SDL_GetRGBA fuction is slow.

Comment: `memcpy(palette, pixels, rgbaImage->pitch*rgbaImage->h)` (by the way it is very misleading to call something palette when it isn't) if CPU is little endian, fallback to GetRGBA otherwise (or implement byte swapping) if you need big endian support too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Keltar! It's working, thank you!